# How to reach model properties inside FluentValidation constructor?

Tags: asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

I have the following validator class:

```
public class ApplicationFormValidator : AbstractValidator<ApplicationForm>
{
    public ApplicationFormValidator()
    {   
       //cause I need to use this variable in a lot of when rules
        bool isGoodEmployee = false;

        RuleFor(x => x)
           .Custom((val, context) =>
           {
               if (val.Type == ApplicationFormType.Employee && val.score > 9)
               {
                   isGoodEmployee = true;
               }
               else
               {
                   isGoodEmployee = false;
               }
           });
    }
}
```

But when I check **isGoodEmployee**  it's always false even I set it to true inside the custom rule.

My question is how to reach the model's properties so I can define some variables to use in later rules.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to reuse some condition I know is to implement additional property in your model:

```
public class ApplicationForm
{
    public ApplicationFormType Type { get; set; }

    public int Score { get; set; }

    public bool IsGoodEmployee => Type == ApplicationFormType.Employee && Score > 9; 
    // get-only property with lambda-like syntax in the last version of C#
}
```

So, your validator could look like this:

```
public class ApplicationFormValidator : AbstractValidator<ApplicationForm>
{
    public ApplicationFormValidator()
    {   
        When(m => m.IsGoodEmployee, () => 
        {
            RuleFor(m => m.SomeProperty) //...
            // rules go here
        }

        RuleFor(m => m.SomeOtherProperty)
            .NotEmpty()
            // rules go here
            .When(m => m.IsGoodEmployee);
    }
}
```

}

Of course, you can say it makes your model "dirty", but it's easy and good-understanding way to implement logic you need.